# Reportviewer with MySQL stored procedure. Report not showing data (winform)

Tags: c#, mysql, reportviewer

I built a form that contains a report viewer and also created a stored procedure in MySQL workbench 8.0. The procedure was tested and works ok. Here is my code:

```
private void LoadReport()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlParameter quote = new MySqlParameter();
            quote = new MySqlParameter("quote", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            quote.Value = quote_id_box.Text;

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            con.Open();

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "project_report";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(quote);

            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dt.Load(dr);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rds = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("pr_DataSet", dt);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

The dataTable is getting a response from MySQL and it has the right data in it but the problem is that the report won't show the information. It gives me

> "the report source has not been defined"

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong? This is my first report ever using report viewer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I would look at your report file's location. I doubt it's a problem with the code you have shown.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I inserted a table in the report but I can't add the propper dataset. Therefore the report is now giving me a datasource error.